# Data scraping using selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am scraping data from a website which is generating data at a certain interval of time. As per my current code, I am closing the browser once it scrapes the data and closes the driver connection. Is it possible to scrape without closing the browser window and close the driver object once the scraping is done(I mean every 15 mins the website is generating new data, I want my driver to scrape data from the initial window instead of invoking a new window each time)? Please let me know a viable solution.

Comment: Do You have to use selenium for that ?? Can U describe more clearly with steps process what You want to get and in which moment?

Comment: You could do it in a while loop and just put a sleep at the end of it... Another solution would be running your data scrape and then enter a while loop until some element is changed(an element that you know is gonna be changed)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use time.sleep() and then use send.keys() to scroll up for loading the new data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).